# Excel Formula to identify date trigger of an expense?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a source sheet that has numeric values (1,1,2,2,3,3, etc) that runs from cell/columns H2:AQ2, Columns H to AQ on Row 3 have a month between Jan 2018 and December 2020

Source Sheet:

[image: Source Sheet]

I need to identify the date month in Row 3 of the column which is the first month a new number (1,2,9, etc) appears in Row 2.

I need a formula for the support sheet to identify this value to trigger expenses on the target sheet.

Target Sheet Trial Formula:

[image: Target Sheet Trial Formula]

Comment: First, it's not super clear what you're asking and how the spreadsheet is laid out. Please use a screenshot if you can. Second, we are not a script-writing service. What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems with that? We're happy to help, we just want you to have tried a bit first yourself.

Comment: A screen shot is hard to grab 36 columns. Let me see if I can example, then I can adapt formula to fit. The key question is how to identify from within a column string a date value over the first time a single number appears? The formula which failed was =IF(Revenue!H2:AQ2=1,Revenue!H$3:AQ3,EOMONTH-30,0). Row 3 lists a date as month/year.

I will create a small spreadsheet showing only four columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want MATCH(): `=MATCH(1,2:2,0)` will return the column number where `1` first appears.  Then use INDEX to return the date:

```
=INDEX(3:3,MATCH(1,2:2,0))
```

Comment: Scott,
I applied the formula =INDEX(Revenue!H$3:AQ$3,MATCH(1,Revenue!H2:AQ,0))

The parens are correct, but it is producing a NAME? error. I am not getting starting month date. Ideas?

I put resulting screen in my question

Comment: You are missing a row reference in the match formula.

Comment: Sleep is a powerful ally! Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

The formula:

=INDEX(Revenue!H$3:AQ$3,MATCH(1,Revenue!H2:AQ2,0))

Solves this problem! Simply need to change the objective number (1,Revenue... for each progressing target number (2,3 etc.)